Grid transformation not taken into account when using gdaltransform (3.10) in command line (anaconda)
I have installed GDAL-3.9.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl using Anaconda and I want to perform coordinate transformations with simple command lines using gdaltransform.
The issue I have is that the grid files needed for the transformation doesn't seem to be used.
Ex : I am trying to convert from WGS84 EPSG:4326 to WGS84 + EGM96 height EPSG:4326+5773
The command line I am using looks like this :
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326+5773
If i look in the proj.db database I can located the expected grid file name WW15MGH.GRD.
I have downloaded this file and installed it in multiple locations, but it never seems to be taken into account.
I have tried installing it in the same folder than the proj.db.
I have tried setting up the environment variable PROJ_DATA and PROJ_LIB and put the grid file in this defined path. But it didn't make it work.
I am out of ideas now.
How can I spot what I am doing wrong?

EPSG:4326 is a 2D system and therefore height is not processed.
projinfo -s epsg:4326 -t epsg:4326+5773
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of Null geographic offset from WGS 84 to WGS 84, 0 m, World.

PROJ string:
+proj=noop

Try EPSG:4979 https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4979/ instead
projinfo -s EPSG:4979 -t EPSG:4326+5773
Candidate operations found: 2
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, WGS 84 to EGM96 height (1), 1 m, World.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +inv +proj=vgridshift +grids=us_nga_egm96_15.tif +multiplier=1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

Test with gdaltransform:
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4979 -t_srs EPSG:4326+5773
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
50 70 100
50 70 96.9851653575897


Thanks for you answer. however I am doubting this is the issue here. I used this in the past and it was working. I just can't get the environement correct this time. Also, doing this conversion gives me a result, in 3D, without errors: gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:32630 -t_srs EPSG:4326 --debug ON Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return. 894000 4995124 100 1.99902956148316 45.0000377974071 100

And I tried your suggestion but without success.

I added a gdaltransform example and used EPSG:4979 that seems to be the current code in the EPSG database. Works for me with GDAL 3.11.0dev and Proj 9.5.0. Conversion from EPSG:32630 into EPSG:4326 is 2D, the z coordinate is just copied as-is.
